# SQL: selecting different values from one column in db's table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `replies`. There is a column inside it called `approval`.

The values I used are `yes` `no`, and `disapproved`

- `yes` is approved by admin and shown to everyone.
- `no` is not approved yet and shown to the admin only.
- `disapproved` is disapproved by admin and shown to none.

Is there a way to select the replies in approval column with two values ? `yes` and `no`.

 because I don't want to show the `disapproved` replies

I search the web and stackoverflow. i got no where maybe because I didn't use the right key words for my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM replies WHERE approval IN ('yes', 'no');
```

Or if there are not other values possible than the three you mentioned:

```
SELECT * FROM replies WHERE approval <> 'disapproved';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `IN` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM replies WHERE approval in ('yes', 'no');
```

[Live fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13b44/1/0). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
SELECT * FROM replies WHERE approval != 'disapproved'
```